# Create alphabetically sorted word cloud

Tags: r, word-cloud

I want to create a word cloud for following data.

```
Red     30
Brown   12
Black   16
Green   33
Yellow  18
Grey    19
White   11
```

My word cloud should look like this:

[image]

In which words are alphabetically sorted and the font of the words is according to the values corresponding to the second column.

Comment: have a look at `order` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns#answer-1296745

Comment: @Floo0 I don't want to order column . I want to create a word cloud which is alphabetically sorted. As far as I know wordcloud() in R creates  a wordcloud in random manner. If random.order
set to false, word cloud will be plotted in decreasing frequency(not alphabetically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can separate each word into letters then assign size per each letter and plot using `ggplot2::geom_text`:

```
library(ggplot2) # ggplot2_2.2.0

# data
df1 <- read.table(text ="
Red     30
Brown   12
Black   16
Green   33
Yellow  18
Grey    19
White   11", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(df1) <- c("col", "size")
# order based on value of size
df1 <- df1[order(df1$col), ]

# separate into letters add size
datPlot <- 
  do.call(rbind,
  lapply(seq(nrow(df1)), function(i){
    myLetter <- c(".", unlist(strsplit(df1$col[i], split = "")))
    data.frame(myLetter = myLetter,
               size = c(10, rep(df1$size[i], length(myLetter) - 1)))
    }))
# each letter gets a sequential number on x axis, y is fixed to 1
datPlot$x <- seq(nrow(datPlot))
datPlot$y <- 1

# plot text
ggplot(datPlot, aes(x, y, label = myLetter, size = size/3)) +
  geom_text(col = "#F89443") +
  scale_size_identity() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]